# Sci-fi film - Scientists studying a (living? magnetic?) force in a facility, which becomes a global threat

Tags: story-identification, movie

I posted the following on rec.arts.sf.written and got a possibility: 'The Magnetic Monster' from 1953. Any others?

Here's the movie:

I'm pretty sure it's from the fifties. I only saw it as a kid.

Scientists are investigating some force (living?) they have captured in some sort of facility. It keeps getting more and more powerful. It becomes a serious global (?) threat. It reminds me in retrospect of 'The Andromeda Strain'- a government/research facility being the site of the movie. I think the force was kind of magnetic - it was not that the force was threatening to explode, but to suck everything in to it (?).

I know that's really not much to go on - I'm pretty sure it was B&W.

It was really riveting to me way back then. I was pretty young which explains the vagueness of my recollection.

Any help appreciated!

Ken

Comment: You're certain it's **not** *The Magnetic Monster*?

Comment: If it was a book, I would have told you "Le titan de l'espace" by Yves Dermeze, because it has that exact plot and it came out in 1954. But since it is a movie, can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: a little different story, but which involves: some force getting bigger and bigger, a facility, and magnetic shields: `the forbidden planet` (a real treat of a movie)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magnetic_Monster sounds like a winner to me.

Comment: Recently watched this: Inventor in black-and-white era inadvertently creates magnetic "life" that pulses destructively every so often, hero scientist leads efforts to understand and then quench the thing.

Answer (score 3):

"The Outer Limits"(TV series 1963-65)

Episode 11 from the 1st season: "It Crawled Out of the Woodwork"?

The story transpires in a research facility, it involves the accidental creation of an energy creature that grows and becomes stronger each time it feeds. It's in black & white and the creature looks like a dark morphing cloud with flashing lights inside of it. Here is the IMDb page which has photos posted, including the creature.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667817/

And here is the 1st 2 minutes of the episode from YouTube, in which the creature is 1st introduced.

Answer (score 2):

A movie with some similarities, but not exactly what you described is:

[The Forbidden Planet (imdb)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049223/)

It contains a lot of what you remember:

- scientists
- investigating some (living?) force
- that keeps getting more and more powerful, until becoming a global threat
- a "government/research" (in reality, some ancient civilisation) facility is prominently featured
- and the effect of the creature (and some containment measures) heavily involves magnetic forces

Maybe this movie fits the bill?...

(and it is a good movie, anyway!)

Comment: Forbidden Planet was in color and the monster was an energy monster created by the machine under the planet based on Morbius's ID when he engaged the brain-machine interface.